# UITableView cells take content from others cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

My `UITableView` cells take content (images) from others cells. I have no idea why that happening, but I am sure that my mistake is silly. At the image below you can see how it looks. Cells on the top take images from the cells on the bottom (facebook and twitter icons).

Here is my code for **cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array1 = [dictionary objectForKey:@"stuff"];

    NSString *cellValue = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue; // загаловок клетки
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:16]; 
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:145/256.0 green:0/256.0 blue:0/256.0 alpha:1.0];    
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"password"] == YES)
        {
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }
    }

    switch(indexPath.section)
    {

        case 2:
        {
            cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        }
        break;

        case 3:
        {
            if (indexPath.row == 0) 
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook"];
            else if (indexPath.row == 1)
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter"];
            else if (indexPath.row == 2)
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"youtube"];
            else
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vk"];
        }
        break;
            default:
            break;
    }




    return cell;
}
```

[image]

How can I fix it ?

Comment: I couldn't see the error in this part of the code but I will propose a way to trace it. Add a `case` for value `1` and `0` (the cases that don't have images) and set `cell.imageView.image` to `nil`. In this case we will know if the cells are getting images from this code or from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells are reused, so you have to set the imageView of your cells to nil whenever you don't want an image to appear. Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array1 = [dictionary objectForKey:@"stuff"];

    NSString *cellValue = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue; // загаловок клетки
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:16]; 
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:145/256.0 green:0/256.0 blue:0/256.0 alpha:1.0];    
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    cell.imageView.image = nil;

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"password"] == YES)
        {
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }
    }

    switch(indexPath.section)
    {

        case 2:
        {
            cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        }
        break;

        case 3:
        {
            if (indexPath.row == 0) 
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook"];
            else if (indexPath.row == 1)
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter"];
            else if (indexPath.row == 2)
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"youtube"];
            else
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vk"];
        }
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }




    return cell;
}
```